# resolve deleted by us and keep the local files

Tags: git, merge, gitignore

I recently added some .txt files to gitignore, but before I pushed gitignore to remote, someone pushed a new commit to the remote. Now when I pull it to my locale branch, I got unmerged paths saying "deleted by us" for those .txt files. How can I resolve the merge so that I can keep my locale .txt files and tell remote to delete .txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling `git checkout --ours [path]` + `git rm --cached [path]` on each of the files you want to remove from revision control but save it locally, then push it to remote.

```
--cached
Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.
```